# SleekXMPP: Get ClientXMPP JID Resource?

Tags: python, xmpp

```
import sleekxmpp

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, password, recipient, wsh):
        print "jid is " + jid
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        print "self jid is " + self.jid
```

I'm using SleekXMPP as above, following their [basic example](http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/sendlogout.html). When I create the SendMsgBot, I supply the jid as user@domain.com/resource. However, the output from the code above gives me:

```
jid is user@domain.com/resource
self jid is user@domain.com
```

Is it possible to find out the resource of a sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP? I know the resource is being used, because the data is there in the raw XMPP stanzas. I see that there is a [JID class](http://sleekxmpp.com/api/xmlstream/jid.html) but I'm not sure how to get from the [ClientXMPP](http://sleekxmpp.com/api/clientxmpp.html) jid to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `self.boundjid` field, which is the JID as set during session binding. Since that is a JID object, you can use `self.boundjid.resource`.

Comment: Also, it is best to check for that after the session has started (ie, in a `'session_start'` event handler). Even if you request a specific resource initially, it is not guaranteed that you will actually be assigned that resource when binding.

Comment: Thanks so much, for both your project and your answer here!